# .NET 8 preview 7 and RC 1 seem to be ignoring IlcGenerateStackTraceData property

Tags: .net-8.0, native-aot

We are using native AOT with IlcDisableReflection=true and IlcGenerateStackTraceData=true.

Up until .NET 8 Preview 6 all was working fine, stack trace metadata was not generated.

When upgrading to .NET 8 Preview 7 or .NET 8 RC1, stack trace metadata started appearing in the resulting published binary despite the IlcGenerateStackTraceData property being true.
Has anyone encountered an issue like this?

Comment: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/core/deploying/trimming/trimming-options?pivots=dotnet-7-0#trimming-framework-library-features

Answer (score 0):

Apparently IlcDisableReflection was renamed to StackTraceSupport